# Need to create JSON using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

```
var scoreX9Single = 0 ;   

function scoreIncrease($player){


     scoreX9Single++;
     localStorage.setItem("scoreX" , scoreX9Single);
     scoreX9 = localStorage.getItem("scoreX");

}
```

This is how i am storing my score in local-storage. I need to store high score in local-storage. Every  time when we play the score should compare with high score and display the result based on highs core.

Comment: i am trying to store the scores in JSON.But not getting how to do that.

Comment: What is the scope of scoreX9 in your code?

Comment: That is a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 localStorage.setItem("scoreX" , JSON.parse(scoreX9Single));
```

?

By the way your scoreX9Single seems to be just a number, which is indeed valid JSON.
So when you read it back from localStorage you HAVE JSON!

Answer (score 1):

You can't store JSON in localstorage but you can stringify it first (then parse it when you need it later)

var names = ["John","Ringo"];

localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(names);

var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);

Answer (score 1):

You need to have json structure as

```
var score= { "highScore": null };
```

Then your code changes as

```
var scoreX9Single = 0 ;   
score.highScore = scoreX9Single;
```

The function:

```
function scoreIncrease($player){
     scoreX9Single++;     

     localStorage.setItem("scoreX" , score); //set json

     scoreX9 = localStorage.getItem("scoreX"); // get json

     var Score = JSON.parse(scoreX9); //parse json

     //go for high score 
     if(Score.highScore < scoreX9Single){
        Score.highScore = scoreX9Single;
     }
     alert("High Score is "+Score.highScore);
}
```